# Is it possible to tell when Alt Beacon last scanned for a beacon on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

We are using beacon monitoring, and store when the beacon was last seen. What we want to make sure is that the phone is still scanning, and there has not been some kind of issue in the app that means bluetooth scanning has stopped. Thus we want to tell when the app last scanned for the beacon.

I know that the logging for alt beacon library shows when bluetooth scanning occured, but the didDetermineStateForRegion is only called when isInRegion changes. Is there an alt beacon api for Android  that allows us to know when the last bluetooth scanned occurred, or how many scans there have been over a time period?

Answer (score 0):

The library has two detection APIs: startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(…) and startRangingBeaconsInRegion(…) the second one will give you a callback ~1 sec with a list of all beacons detected.  Use this to verify detections are still happening.

Both APIs do the same scanning under the hood.  The only difference is in the callbacks — monitoring just gives you callbacks on first appearance and after disappearance.  If you want to confirm regular detection, use ranging. You can even use both at the same time.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Will check it out.